# Marsh puzzle with empty block columns is not working

Tags: the-witness

[image: Marsh Puzzle not Working]
I don't seem to understand why this solution to the puzzle is not working. However, please don't respond with a solution because I'll figure that out ;)

Edit: I found a solution, but feel free to reply to my question still, because I'm still curious.

Answer (score 18):

There are two empty columns between those 2x1 blocks.  Your solution assumes there is only one.